# When someone adds only tags to a question, is it regarded as an improvement?

Tags: discussion, review-queue

So someone has been adding tags to existing questions and they have been popping up in the review queue.

There have been existing tags in the questions and the person is simply adding one more tag e.g. `cookies`.

The options for reviewing are "Approve - This edit clearly improves the post." or "Reject - This edit fails to improve the post."

In my mind adding a single slightly relevant tag does neither.  Which is the most appropriate response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Relevant tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) are an improvement since they help to [sort questions into specific, well-defined categories](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), which helps in the [Search functions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) and the [Watched/Ignored Tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) functions.

So if the tag(s) add relevant information to the question(s) being asked (not the potential answers), then they should be approved. Often new users will do so to build up their reputation without diving into answering, so it encourages participation on the site as well.

If all of the added tags are [irrelevant](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits) or tangential, then the edit is clearly not an improvement and should be rejected. If some of the tags are irrelevant and some are relevant, then [improve the edit](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits) to remove the irrevlant tags.